# SharedPreferences уничтожить запись

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-shared-preferences

Как уничтожить запись в *SharedPreferences*?

Без использования диспетчера приложений, кодом уничтожить определенные записи, чтобы даже *SharedPreferences.contains* видел что записи нету.

пробовал делать `editor.putString( name, null );`, но в *xml-файле* остаются следы: `<null name="pass" />`

но все работает: *SharedPreferences.contains* не видит запись, но следы остались.

Comment: пробовал делать         editor.putString( name, null );
но в xml файле остаются следы, <null name="pass" />

Comment: но все работает SharedPreferences.contains не видит запись, но следы остались

Comment: для редактирования вопроса и внесения в него дополнительной информации можно воспользоваться кнопкой [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Api смотреть пробовали?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html метод remove

Comment: Хе, поспешил, думал писать что не работает, заработал когда дописал одну строчку, все работает следов нету! editor.remove(name);
        editor.commit();

Comment: Совет, не используйте commit() используйте apply(). В чем разница - apply() сохраняет изменения в SharedPrefrences, но не коммитит сразу на диск, что затратно. Сохранение произойдет чуть позже, сразу всех изменений что накопились за это время.

Comment: ок, спасибо огромное